# Acoustic fingerprint code for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, voice-recognition, acoustics

I've started looking on the subject of Acoustic Fingerprint (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint) for a pet project of mine for the iOS and I was wondering if there are:

1. Any opensource libraries or source code for the iOS that handle this?
2. Assuming I'm a veteran jack of all trades coder, is it very problematic to implement this myself if there is no open-source versions?
3. Will the Accelerate DSP library in iOS able to handle such a task?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Not of my knowledge
2. No problem for a veteran, that won't be easy, but achievable.
3. Never looked into.

Even in java, [this](http://www.redcode.nl/blog/2010/06/creating-shazam-in-java/) might be an interesting reading.

Before doing anything, *especially if you intend to sell on AppStore*, take care that these techniques/algorithms are patented. Read [what happened](http://www.redcode.nl/blog/2010/07/patent-infringement/) to the above blog post writer.

Answer (score 6):

you may want to check out the [EchoPrint CodeGen](https://github.com/echonest/echoprint-codegen) library by The Echo Nest. They even have a fully functional [iOS code example](https://github.com/echonest/echoprint-ios-sample).

You can find some additional links to open source audio fingerprinting related software in [this MusicBrainz article](http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/AudioFingerprint), but AFAIK the EchoPrint library is the only one that has a license that is compatible with iOS apps.

Good Luck!

Comment: EchoPrint has two big issues 1) It is just for comparing the same inputs i.e. it is almost impossible to match a clear recoding from a CD with a sample recorded with a phone from TV/radio with background noises. 2) It works reliably only for very long samples (~30 seconds). ...We tried to adapt the EchoPrint's CodeGen for shorter samples and noisy samples, but it was huge hit-and-miss (i.e. random) and good just for amusement of our audience :)

Answer (score 0):

Will the Accelerate DSP library in iOS able to handle such a task? 
NO

I also notice that you put the tag "voice recognition". Just to make sure voice recognition as nothing to do with audio identification/acoustic fingerprinting !!